# How to use Coroutines Flow to modify one view based on the change in another view?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-android-extensions

I have two edit texts When ever I typed in one edit text I want to emit the data and populate in another edit text. Find below the codes I have tried

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var editText : EditText? = null
    private var editText1 : EditText? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val linearLayout = LinearLayout(baseContext)
        linearLayout.orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
        editText = EditText(baseContext)
        editText1 = EditText(baseContext)
        linearLayout.addView(editText)
        linearLayout.addView(editText1)
        setContentView(linearLayout)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            sendData().collect{
                editText!!.setText(it)
            }
        }

    }

    private fun sendData()  = flow  {
        editText1?.addTextChangedListener {
            emit(it.toString())
        }


    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to use `Flow` for that?

```
editText?.addTextChangedListener{ editable ->
            editText1.setText(editable.toString())
}
```

EDIT:
Since this is only for learning purposes, there is a chance to use `callbackFlow`. However you have to be careful to close the callback after emition:

```
fun listenTextChange(): Flow<String> = callbackFlow{
   editText.addTextChangeListener{
        offer(it.toString())
   }
   awaitClose{ editText.removeListener() //if there is one or just make the callback null }
}
```

And then, you can do:

```
listenTextChange().collect{text -> 
    editText1.setText(text)
}
```

Comment: I know that. It is just a use case I am doing to check possibility of using Flow/Coroutines instead rxjava

Comment: Thank you. I will check this one

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin extension function version:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
val EditText.textFlow: Flow<String>
    get() = callbackFlow {
        val textWatcher = doAfterTextChanged { offer(it.toString()) }
        awaitClose { removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher) }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is below;
Whenever you type in editText, TextView will be updated.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var editText: EditText
private lateinit var textView: TextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_query)
    textView = findViewById(R.id.text_view)

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        listenTextChange().collect { str ->
            textView.text = str
        }
    }

}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun listenTextChange(): Flow<String> = callbackFlow {
    val watcher = object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            //
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            //
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            trySend(editable.toString())
        }

    }
    editText.addTextChangedListener(watcher)
    awaitClose {
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(watcher)
    }
}
```

}